# Make a new df column based on value in another column and another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and need to make a new column in df1 (df1["y"]) with values from df2 (df2["y"]) based on values in df1["x"], df2["x_1] and df2["x_2"] with conditions that result with the df_result.

```
df1:
x
100
200
300
400
500
600
```

```
df2:
x_1 x_2 y
100 300 1000
400 600 2000
```

```
df_result:
x   y
100 1000
200 1000
300 1000
400 2000
500 2000
600 2000
```

Comment: how do you know 600 maps to 2000, it's not in df2

Comment: How is the mapping from 300 to 1000 determined?  This is ambiguous given `df2`.

Comment: As mention the example was incorrect. But I have fixed the datafremes. I hope some have a good function so I can end up with the df_result.

Comment: Is the step fixed to be `100`? Like `400-600` is expanded into `400, 500, 600`?

Comment: now your `df2` is missing 200

Answer (score 0):

I assume you didn't complete df2 since x=600 isn't there for both x1 and x2. However I believe you want `melt` here

`pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['y'], value_vars=['x_1', 'x_2'])`

```
      y variable  value
0  1000      x_1    100
1  2000      x_1    300
2  2000      x_1    200
3  1000      x_2    300
4  2000      x_2    500
5  2000      x_2    600
```

Comment: As I can see the answer don't end up as the df_result I was after.